# Using Magento 2 backend on multiple computers

Tags: magento2, database

We can work in the backend on multiple computers, but the system sees it as 1 user working. Case explanation:

For example, if I am working on an particular customer order in the sales environment, someone else will see the same screen. If someone also access the sales environment, and this person take a different order than the screen I was working on, it's changing as well. This is really not efficent working.

Anybody support please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Stores > Configuration > Advanced` then select Admin then Expand the Security section set “Yes” in the Admin Account Sharing field.Save Configuration and flush cache.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I appreciate this, however, I am aware how to set this up. The problem is, that the database are linked to one user, meaning that every step I make in the backend on one computer, other user on different computer will have the same screen. On magento 1, every employee using the backend on different computer were able to work independently.

Comment: Create new user using ACL and give him all the privileges of current user have.this may resolve your problem.

Comment: Done and fixed! Thank  you so much sir!

Comment: Glad to know. Your most welcome.